# Two-way tabulation with cypher, neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a network with two types of nodes: (n:type1)-[r]->(m:type2). The type1 nodes have a property, called, which can take values True or False. I would like a query that for each node of type2, gives the total of True's and Falses' from the nodes related to it.

I could do this in two passes:

```
match (n:type1)-[r]->(m:type2) where n.called return m.id, count(n);
match (n:type1)-[r]->(m:type2) where not n.called return m.id, count(n);
```

But I would like to be able to do it in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
match (n:type1)-[r]->(m:type2) 
return m.id, n.called, count(n);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.